# Print numbers sequentially using printf with filling zeroes

Tags: c++, c

in C++, using printf I want to print a sequence of number, so I get, from a "for" loop;

```
1
2
...
9
10
11
```

and I create files from those numbers. But when I list them using "ls" I get

```
10
11
1
2
..
```

so instead of trying to solve the problem using bash, I wonder how could I print;

```
0001
0002
...
0009
0010
0011
```

and so on

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
i = 45;
printf("%04i", i);
```

=>

```
0045
```

Basically, 0 tells printf to fill with '0', 4 is the digit count and 'i' is the placeholder for the integer (you can also use 'd').

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf#vprintf.2C_vfprintf.2C_vsprintf.2C_vsnprintf.2C_and_vasprintf) about the format placeholders.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using C++, then why are you using `printf()`?

Use `cout` to do your job.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <iomanip>

 using namespace std;

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {

    for(int i=0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        cout << setfill('0') << setw(4) << i << endl;
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

And this is how your output will look:

```
0000
0001
0002
0003
0004
0005
0006
0007
0008
0009
0010
0011
0012
0013
0014
```

C++ to the rescue!

Answer (score 5):

`printf("%04d\n", Num);` should work.  Take a look at [the printf man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/printf/).

Answer (score 4):

```
printf("%04d", n);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%4.4d\n", num);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple case:

```
for(int i = 0; i != 13; ++i)
  printf("%*d", 2, i)
```

Why "%*d" ? Because you don't want to hardcode the number of leading digits; it depends on the largest number in the list. With IOStreams, you have the same flexibility with `setw(int)`

Answer (score 0):

[This article explain what you're trying to do](http://www.deitel.com/articles/cplusplus_tutorials/20060218/cplusplus_streamformatstates_streammanipulators_Page4.html)

It is called "padding with leading zeroes"

Answer (score 0):

You use %04d as your format string for the integer.